# How to service a Gatsby website with multiple domains and its contents?

Tags: url, dns, gatsby, contentful, domain-aliasing

I built a website using Gatsby, Contentful, and deployed on Netlify.
I am going to run this website with multiple domain aliases.

ex:
`alias1.example.com`
`alias2.example.com`

In that case, the aliases work well and the website have to show contents that belong to the own alias in Contentful.
For example, let's say the current alias is `alias1`, then the website have to fetch data only have `alias1` entry from Contentful.

What I was trying is to add the codes to identify alias in `gatsby-config.js` using `windows.location.href`, and set `siteUrl` as dynamic, but it didn't work.

I am not sure it could be possible and how to implement it.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it the same deployment on Netlify for both? If not, try setting a variable in `.env` file then you can switch behaviour based on that.

Comment: Or you can check the netlify env variables https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#deploy-urls-and-metadata

Answer (score 2):

The best (and almost the only) approach to achieving this is to use an [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/) for each site/alias and configure the deploy command to trigger and use the variables for each site. In that way, each deploy will fetch the data from each Contentful environment.

In your `gatsby-config.js` (above the module exportation) add:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

The next step is to create one environment file for each alias. In your project root:

- `.env.alias1`
- `.env.alias2`

Each file should contain your environment variables from Contentful:

```
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN:12345
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID:12345
```

Then, in your `gatsby-config.js` just replace your hardcoded variables for the ones in your environment files:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
  options: {
    spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  },
},
```

The last step is to configure the deploy scripts to trigger each desired alias. In your `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "jest",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\""
    "develop-alias1": "gatsby develop GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=alias1"
    "build-alias1": "gatsby build GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=alias1"
    "develop-alias2": "gatsby develop GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=alias2"
    "build-alias2": "gatsby build GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=alias2"
  },
```

Note that you will replace the default `gatsby develop` and `gatsby build` for your aliased commands.

By adding this bunch of configuration, for each `develop` or `build`/deploy you are telling your Gatsby project to which environment file should look at (it will take your `.env.alias*` instead). Each file will contain the keys for each environment in Contentful with different content in it, allowing you to deploy aliased sites with different content using a unique CMS.

Comment: Hi @Frerran. Thanks for your detailed answer. And what I want to build is to use only one Contentful space. I could fetch data from Contentful comparing entries with alias over graphQL queries. So just want to get only alias in `gatsby-config.js` file and could use it in the pages.

Comment: So is it possible to get domain before defining type of windows using `windows.location.href`?

Comment: You can if you use a environment variable to add manually the subdomain or if you fetch it via CMS/API request before the building process. At the moment you use a `window` object you can't because the project is built.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the most critical problem of Gatsby, and almost people has hard time with it.

The core problem is the "browser environment" **is not available** when you "build" Gatsby project. And **`gatsby-config.js` is used for NodeJS environment**. In other words, everything sticked with `window` variable is not accessible.

You should read the offical docs about gatsby build process here:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/#build-time-vs-runtime.

Solution: you can define different "scripts" in `package.json` for each alias which you can provide environment variables for NodeJS environment. Then in `gatsby-config.js`, use `dotenv` package to read passed variables.

You can read more here about using environment variables: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/#reach-skip-nav